# How to write an IntelliJ IDEA Plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

IDEA has many plugins to use. I.e. `IDEtalk` is one of them which I use. How can I code a simple plugin that just connects to Internet and shows a web page? (no need for an address bar but it is not a problem to be). I want my plugin's shortcut's  button locate at my IDE as like `IDEtalk, Commander, Maven Projects etc`.

Any ideas?

Comment: I wrote a sum-up of my experiences in the following answer: [IntelliJ IDEA Plugin Development](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15718991/675065)

Comment: I wrote this a while back hope it helps anyone tackling this “So you want to develop an IntelliJ plugin” by Idan Koch https://link.medium.com/UYZ2c8bQGV

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto_03.html) and the source code of the other plug-ins available in the [public git repository](http://git.jetbrains.org/) of the Community Edition.

Comment: thanks. However can thar plugins locate as a button at Intellij IDEA window?(maybe they are not called as plugin)

Comment: Yes, plug-ins can have their own tool window buttons and open panels, check the source code of the existing plug-ins to see how it works.

Comment: Looks like "public git repository" do not contain source code anymore. "List all projects" is an empty page. Has it moved to somewhere else?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Creating Your First Plugin](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/getting_started.html) guide on JetBrains web site. It covers all the needed steps from plugin creation to deployment to the plugin repository.

You might also want take a look in the source code of a simple plugin like [Twitter Integration Plugin](https://github.com/Shpota/twitter-plugin) which I recently implemented. Or check a more complex one [like this one](https://sashashpota.com/2018/10/30/why-you-need-to-implement-a-plugin.html).